# How to find the max. absolute sequential difference of two values in a given range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, range, difference

I have got a specific Range e.g B2-I2 (which can vary) that contains values e.g 1,2,4,5,34,4,23,12. The aim is to have a macro which finds the largest absolute difference in that given range when the function is executed. In the above example the largest abs. difference would be  30 (as 34-4).

Comment: Are the numbers stored in an Array?

Comment: Why do you need a macro?  Why not just a worksheet formula?  What have you tried and where have you run into trouble?

Comment: i guess an array would be the best option to apply as it fits the purpose. The aim is, as described, to have a function which does the calculations and return the value which reflects the max. absolute difference between two values. And why has my question been downgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, y As Long, ValueArr As Long, ValueY As Long, MaxDiff As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        arr = Application.Transpose(.Range("B2:I2").Value)

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

            ValueArr = Abs(arr(i, 1))

            For y = 2 To 9

                ValueY = Abs(.Cells(2, y).Value)

                If ValueArr - ValueY > MaxDiff Then
                    MaxDiff = ValueArr - ValueY
                End If

            Next y

        Next i

        MsgBox MaxDiff

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @alowflyingpig the OP ask if it can be done with find function. Unfortunately, based on my experience, find function has not that kind of functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're wanting to find the largest sequential difference, if so, try this ...

```
Public Function GetLargestDifference(ByVal objCells As Range) As Double
    Dim objCell As Range, i As Long, dblThisDiff As Double, arrValues()

    ' Put the (potentially) non sequential set of cells into a one dimensional array.
    For Each objCell In objCells
        ReDim Preserve arrValues(i)
        arrValues(i) = objCell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next

    ' Now process that array and check for the max difference.
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrValues) - 1
        dblThisDiff = arrValues(i) - arrValues(i + 1)
        If dblThisDiff > GetLargestDifference Then GetLargestDifference = dblThisDiff
    Next
End Function
```

... there's no error checking for non numeric values but you can add that as required.

If you need to do an absolute check then replace this line ...

```
dblThisDiff = arrValues(i) - arrValues(i + 1)
```

... with this ...

```
dblThisDiff = Abs(arrValues(i) - arrValues(i + 1))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Skin, thank you very much for your quick reply. your code is something where one has to typ in the function and specify the lenght of the range. My aim was rather where I specify the lenght of the range and the start point in the macro in advance and the macro, when executed, the calcuation. I will try to add these elements in your code. Thank you for the kickoff.